# How to get time from 00 to 23 using recursive CTE?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, recursive-query, recursive-cte

How do I get hours of a day from 00 hrs to 23 hrs using recursive CTE?

It  gives hours 00 to 24, but I need to exclude the 24 hrs in my result set or in other words I need only up to 00 to 23 hrs

My Code:

```
DECLARE @calenderDate DATETIME2(0) = '2019-05-16 05:00:00'
DECLARE @hr1Week int = 0

;with numcte AS  
       (  
         SELECT 0 [num]  
         UNION all  
         SELECT [num] + 1 FROM numcte WHERE [num] < (Select  datediff(HOUR, @hr1Week, dateadd(DAY, 1, @hr1Week)))
       )        

select * from numcte
```

It  gives hours 00 to 24, but I need to exclude the 24 hrs in my result set or in other words I need only up to 00 to 23 hrs

Actual result:

```
num
----
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
```

Expected Result:

```
num
---
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of
`Select datediff(HOUR, @hr1Week, dateadd(DAY, 1, @hr1Week))`, changing it to
`Select datediff(HOUR, @hr1Week, dateadd(DAY, 1, @hr1Week)) - 1`
will return the hours up to 23 only

```
DECLARE @calenderDate DATETIME2(0) = '2019-05-16 05:00:00'
DECLARE @hr1Week int = 0

;with numcte AS  
(  
     SELECT 0 [num]  
     UNION all  
     SELECT [num] + 1 FROM numcte WHERE [num] < 
      (SEELCT datediff(HOUR, @hr1Week, dateadd(DAY, 1, @hr1Week)) -1)
)        

SELECT * FROM numcte
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=507f4b4f4661628956f658a31222a22f)